# Meaning of sentence. "He is not vigilant like you"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

> He is not vigilant like you.

Does it mean that

1. you are vigilant.
2. Or you are not vigilant like him.

I am really confused by the sentence whether it's a compliment or complaint?

Comment: Your sentence is perfectly idiomatic, but to be strictly correct it should be '...like you are'. It means that the person being addressed_ is_ vigilant, but another person is less so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could actually go either way, but I think it mostly likely means you ARE vigilant, he is not. If it was phrased:

> Like you, he is not vigilant.

That means neither person is vigilant.

If it was:

> He is not vigilant, like you.

Then again, neither person is vigilant.

But because it is phrased:

> He is not vigilant like you.

Then I'd treat "vigilant like you" as a single phrase, meaning you are vigilant and he is not like you. Therefore he is not vigilant. The other phrasings all specifically break "you" from "vigilant" with a comma.