# Usage of 'not _ like you'

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What do these sentence mean?

1. Jack is not a singer like John.
2. Jack is not a singer, like John.

Comment: The comma in the second version indicates that ***like John*** is a ***sentence adverb*** there. So it applies to the entirety of the preceding statement *(Jack is not a singer. Similarly, John is not a singer)*. To avoid confusion, we normally put the sentence adverb component ***before*** the main statement: *Like John, Jack is not a singer.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of sentence. "He is not vigilant like you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471933/meaning-of-sentence-he-is-not-vigilant-like-you)

Answer (score 0):

Of course context influences meaning, so this is one interpretation, perhaps the most linguistically conservation reasonable estimate.

> 1. Jack is not a singer like John.

**Both** Jack and John are singers, but if you were to compare their singing, Jack does not sing like John. The *implication* here is that John is a better singer and is more suitably *referred to as a* **singer**. The full sentence might read: "*Jack is not a singer like John [is a singer].*"

> 2. Jack is not a singer, like John.

In this second example, the comma separates a complete clause, i.e., that Jack *is not a singer*. However the omitted verb from the second, dependent clause can go in two divergent ways: either (1) *like* Jack not being a singer, neither is John a singer. The implication here is that **neither** Jack **Nor** John are singers, at all. It is not one of their hobbies, and there is no implication of skill. However, it could also be read as (2) "*Jack is not a singer, like (as an example of what a "singer" is:) John.*" This interpretation might sound more natural to you if you add inflection to it.It is a semantically acceptable although slightly ironic use of the word "*like*".